# Displaying the last N modified files?

Tags: bash, shell, ls

How can I list the 10 most recently modified files of a certain extension, not all files, or the files modified during the last 2 days for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use find for this. Let's say we want all .py files in the current directory modified in the last 2 days:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -name '*.py' -mtime -2
```

Answer (score 2):

With zsh

```
ls -ld -- *.ext(om[1,10])
```

for the last two days:

```
ls -ld -- *.ext(m-2)
```

Otherwise, if filenames don't contain newline characters, you can always do:

```
ls -lrtd -- *.ext | tail -n 10
```

And for files modified in the last two days POSIXly:

```
find . ! -name . -prune -name '*.ext' -mtime -2 -exec ls -ld {} +
```

Comment: I am using bash. How can I alter the last command for a specific number of days or files ?

Comment: There is no easy way to do this with plain `ls` in bash afaik.